How to create a panda DataFrame containing tuples?
import pandas as pd
dict={'name':'theName','data':('a','b','c')}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

I would like:




name
data




1
theName
('a','b','c')



but instead I get:




name
data




1
theName
'a'


2
theName
'b'


3
theName
'c'




Wrap your dictionary in a list:
dic = {'name': 'theName', 'data': ('a','b','c')}
df = pd.DataFrame([dic])

Or use a dictionary of lists:
dic = {'name': ['theName'], 'data': [('a','b','c')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

Output:
      name       data
0  theName  (a, b, c)

